# Implementation specific questions

Tags: discussion, question, definition

Is it ok to ask questions specific to a certain platform

examples:

> What are good color themes for jQuery UI?
>
> what type of waiting animation should I use in silverlight?

The general idea of the questions is on topic but this is not an implementation site, or is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's okay to mention the implementation *as a constraint*. If the question doesn't hold up when you cross out the implementation, it probably doesn't belong on UI.

Answer (score 1):

My job title is "interaction engineer" and I *very strongly* support that job title as my preferred way to engage in user interface design. "Interaction engineering" - as we've defined it at my employer - centers on being able to build what you can design, because knowing both worlds enables you to make better judgment calls regarding implementation details.

As such, I think we should allow these questions. If a designer is asking about how to implement something, but it's definitely a UI question, then absolutely we should offer them a place to do that.